# Pod behaves different in two different Jenkins Jobs on same K8s cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, jenkins

I have created an image and uploaded to docker:

```dockerfile
FROM jenkins/inbound-agent:jdk11 as agent

LABEL maintainer="JoSSte <re@dacted>"

USER root
ENV TZ=Europe/Copenhagen
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/"${TZ}" /etc/localtime && echo "${TZ}" > /etc/timezone \
&&  dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata 

# update apt cache
RUN apt-get update \
&&  apt-get upgrade -qy \
&&  apt-get install -y curl lsb-release ca-certificates apt-transport-https software-properties-common gnupg2

# add php8 repo
RUN curl -sSLo /usr/share/keyrings/deb.sury.org-php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg \
&&  sh -c 'echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/deb.sury.org-php.gpg] https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list' \
&&  apt-get update

# install php8 & composer
RUN apt-get install -qy rsync zip php8.2-curl php8.2-gd apache2 php8.2 unzip php8.2-mysql php8.2-zip php8.2-mbstring php-xdebug php-pear* \
&&  curl -sSLo composer-setup.php https://getcomposer.org/installer \
&&  php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer \
&&  composer self-update  

# Cleanup old packagess
RUN apt-get -qy autoremove

USER jenkins

ENTRYPOINT ["jenkins-slave"]
```

Which I have used fine in a Jenkins build environment with docker agents.

Now I am changing my setup to work in kubernetes, so I made sure that things work as expected:

```groovy
podTemplate(containers: [
    containerTemplate(name: 'php8builder', image: 'jstevnsvig/jenkins-build-slave-php:v8.2', command: 'sleep', args: '99d')
  ]) {

    node(POD_LABEL) {
        container('php8builder') {
            stage('list apt packages') {
                sh '/bin/sh -c "dpkg-query -l | cat"'
            }
            stage('dump php version') {
                sh '/bin/sh -c "php --version"'
            }
            stage('dump /usr/local/bin files') {
                sh 'ls /usr/local/bin'
            }
            stage('dump composer version') {
                sh '/bin/sh -c "composer --version"'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works beautifully:

> ```
>  + /bin/sh -c php --version
>  PHP 8.2.1 (cli) (built: Jan 13 2023 10:38:46) (NTS)
>  Copyright (c) The PHP Group
>  Zend Engine v4.2.1, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
>      with Zend OPcache v8.2.1, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
>      with Xdebug v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2022, by Derick Rethans
> ```

...

> ```
>   + ls /usr/local/bin
>   composer
>   jenkins-agent
>   jenkins-slave
> ```

...

> ```
>  + /bin/sh -c composer --version
>  Composer version 2.5.1 2022-12-22 15:33:54
> ```

BUT

When I then tried to run it in a pipeline (this has worked before with all the agents defined in the Jenkins configuration - but I want to have less configuration in case of things going wrong), the same image , on the same Jenkins server in the same kubernetes cluster, can't find php or composer... :

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent { 
        kubernetes {
            yamlFile 'KubernetesPod.yaml'
            retries 2
          }
        }
    options {
        disableConcurrentBuilds()
    }
    stages {
        stage ('Staging'){
            steps {
                echo "looking for composer"
                sh 'ls /usr/local/bin'
            }
        }
        stage('run php') {
            steps {
                container('phpbuilder') {
                    sh 'php --version'
                    sh 'php src/test.php'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### KubernetesPod.yaml

```yaml
# https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin/blob/master/examples/declarative_from_yaml_file/KubernetesPod.yaml
metadata:
  labels:
    some-label: some-label-value
spec:
  containers:

  - name: phpbuilder
    image: jstevnsvig/jenkins-build-slave-php:v8.2
    command:
    - sleep
    args:
    - 99d
    #env:
    #- name: CONTAINER_ENV_VAR
    #  value: maven
```

Then composer isn't found:

> ```
>   looking for composer
>   + ls /usr/local/bin
>   jenkins-agent
>   jenkins-slave
> ```

...

> ```
>   + php --version
>   PHP 8.2.1 (cli) (built: Jan 13 2023 10:38:46) (NTS)
>   Copyright (c) The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v4.2.1, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v8.2.1, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
>       with Xdebug v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2022, by Derick Rethans
> ```

As I stated bove, I have used this image in my previous build setup with the jenkins cloud config built in

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent { label 'php8' }
...
```

and I have confirmed that it still works on this cluster - so WHY doesn't it work when i provide kubernetes yaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pipeline configuration is missing one thing which is `defaultContainer` directive.

Please note that by default `Jenkins` will run 2 containers in one pod. One will be `jnlp` even if you don't define it and second you container defined in your `KubernetesPod.yaml`.

So to be able to run things on your custom container your pipeline should looks like this:

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent { 
        kubernetes {
            defaultContainer '<<you container name from yaml file>>'
            yamlFile 'KubernetesPod.yaml'
            retries 2
          }
        }
    options {
        disableConcurrentBuilds()
    }
    stages {
        stage ('Staging'){
            steps {
                echo "looking for composer"
                sh 'ls /usr/local/bin'
            }
        }
        stage('run php') {
            steps {
                container('phpbuilder') {
                    sh 'php --version'
                    sh 'php src/test.php'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please see more examples in [plugin doc](https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes/#plugin-content-declarative-pipeline).

I forgot to mention that you can also run single container in pod by replacing default `jnlp` since you where just adding stuff to `jenkins-agent` image. You can use following manifest to accomplish that

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    role: agent
  name: jenkins-slave
  namespace: jenkins
spec:
  serviceAccountName: jenkins-agent
  containers:
  - name: jnlp
    image: <<your custom container>>
    args: ['\$(JENKINS_SECRET)', '\$(JENKINS_NAME)']
```

Comment: So essentially my code was running on the jnlp container. no wonder it was behaving differently

Comment: I edited my original answer since you can use your custom container image as `jnlp`.